# Wicked gem in rails, link_to previous_wizard_path but want to save object in between

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, wizard

I implemented the wicked gem and it works quite nice.  Using the rails cast got it to go between parts of the various steps using link_tos.  this is great but it doesn't obviously do the submit_tag like when you click "save document" at the bottom of each page...  I would like something to happen to call the update method in the controller with the data from that form but I am not sure how to do this with the standard link_to and previous_wizard_path and next_wizard_path helpers, as those do not call the update but the show it seems.

So not sure, is the link_to to navigate between steps not the preferred way if data has to be saved from each form step in between?

Answer (score 0):

well, usually, you use a form with submit button for each wizard step - just as in the railscast.
the use of link_to is only presented as a way for skipping steps.